# Why Button in kivy is not responding?

Tags: python, button, kivy

I'm following the kivy course from freecodecamp. I've compared my code to the author's one and everything looks the same. Here is a zip archive with my code

[download code in zip archive](https://megawrzuta.pl/download/f874b099ebd7557fec231f8e27b7be02.html)

As I said I've compared my code to the original but everything looks fine

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because The linked website is just an advertisement.

Comment: No, it's nor advertisment. I just don't know where upload it. It's mediafire-like website and I use it very often. Try before you hate

Comment: There is no hate involved. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not post links to code. When I go to that site, all I see is ads.

Comment: Sorry but it's the only site like this I know where I don't have to register. And there are so much files so I cannot paste the code here